# How do I give discord access to my hdd?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I am trying to upload an image to discord that is on my hdd. Discord is giving me this error: `Error opening directory '/media': Permission denied` when trying to navigate to the image. How do I give discord access?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem while using Discord installed via snap (By default, every application installed from Ubuntu Software is running from /snap, I think.)
The solution was simple.

Open the **Ubuntu Software** and search for Discord. If you can see it installed here, there should be three options: Run, Uninstall and Permissions.
Click *permissions* and make sure that *read/write* on removable media is turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, the easiest way doesn't use snap or terminal.

Settings > Applications > Discord > Read/Write on removable storage.

I used it after looking at this. I remembered there was a permissions portion to the settings app.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the owner or the permissions over the directory that causes the error:

**For changing owner:**

`chown -R new-owner:owner-group directory` -> `chown -R sam:sam media`

**For changing permissions:**

`chmod -R 754 directory` -> `chmod -R 754 media`

If these commands don't work, try executing your application with sudo, it should have permissions in that mode.

Hope this helps, good luck!